# Grails application with mysql datasource does not store checkbox bit values

Tags: mysql

In my Grails application, I have two domain classes...Person and Course. There exists a one to many relationship between the two (a course can have multiple persons registered). As a result, the default scaffolding will show me a list of all the persons registered in the course in show.gsp.

I modified show.gsp to add "paid" and "attended" checkboxes:

```
<g:if test="${courseInstance?.persons}">
            <br />
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <g:sortableColumn property="person"
                            title="${message(code: 'person.lastName.label', default: 'Person')}" />
                        <g:sortableColumn property="paid"
                            title="${message(code: 'person.paid.label', default: 'Paid')}" />
                        <g:sortableColumn property="attended"
                            title="${message(code: 'person.paid.attended', default: 'Attended')}" />
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <g:set var="counter" value="${1}" />
                    <g:each in="${courseInstance.persons}" status="i" var="p">
                        <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                            <td>
                                ${counter}
                            </td>
                            <td class="property-value" aria-labelledby="persons-label"><g:link
                                    controller="person" action="show" id="${p.id}">
                                    ${p?.encodeAsHTML()}
                                </g:link></td>
                            <td><g:checkBox name="paid" value="${p.paid}"
                                    onclick="${remoteFunction(action:'togglePaid', id:p.id,
                                params:'\'completed=\' + this.checked')}" /></td>
                            <td><g:checkBox name="attended" value="${p.attended}"
                                    onclick="${remoteFunction(action:'toggleAttended', id:p.id,
                                params:'\'completed=\' + this.checked')}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <g:set var="counter" value="${counter + 1}" />
                    </g:each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </g:if>
```

And in my class controller I added:

```
class CourseController {

static scaffold = true

def toggleAttended = {
    def person = Person.get(params.id)
    if (person){
        person.attended = params.completed == 'true'
        person.save()
    }
    render ''
}

def togglePaid = {
    def person = Person.get(params.id)
    if (person){
        person.paid = params.completed == 'true'
        person.save()
    }
    render ''
}

}
```

When I check/uncheck the checkboxes, the values are remembered successfully. But I notice that my MySQL database does not store any values for those three checkboxes, whether they are checked OR unchecked:

```
mysql> SELECT paid, attended, pfa FROM person;
+------+----------+-----+
| paid | attended | pfa |
+------+----------+-----+
|      |          |     |
+------+----------+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The columns are of type "bit". I'm wondering how the values are being remembered if nothing is being stored in the database. Also, do I need to add extra code in my controllers to update the values in the database? Or should this automatically be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Change your select to SELECT paid+0, attended+0, pfa+0 FROM person; and see if you can see the values.  The mysql client cannot render bit values.  It's a very very old bug.

Comment: Oh wow, that worked. Should I use that syntax for any operation (INSERT, UPDATE, etc.)? Is there any way to modify the application so that I will not have to use that syntax? Also, would you be able to point me to any documentation/resources about it? I've been looking but I can't seem to find much...thank you!

Comment: There's nothing you can do in grails about this.  This is a limitation in the mysql command line client.  It has nothing to do with your application.  The only time you would need to use that syntax is if using the mysql command line client. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28422

Comment: I've moved my comments into an answer so you can accept it since it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your select to SELECT paid+0, attended+0, pfa+0 FROM person; and see if you can see the values. The mysql client cannot render bit values. It's a very very old bug.

There's nothing you can do in grails about this. This is a limitation in the mysql command line client. It has nothing to do with your application. The only time you would need to use that syntax is if using the mysql command line client.

[bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28422](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28422)